# Determine whether $f$, $g$, and $h$ are ring homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am doing my homework here and need to make sure I am on the correct tract.

1. Define $f:\mathbb{Z} → M_{2}\mathbb{(R )}$ by $f(x)=\begin{bmatrix} x & 0 \\ 0 & x \end{bmatrix}$  for all $x∈\mathbb{Z}$
2. Define $g:\mathbb{Z} → M_{2}\mathbb{(R )}$ by $g(x)=\begin{bmatrix} x & x \\ x & x \end{bmatrix}$  for all $x∈\mathbb{Z}$
3. Define $h = \mathbb{Z} → \mathbb{Z}$ by $h(x) = x^3$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$
4. Consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ and the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{6} = \{\bar{0}, ...,\bar{4}, \bar{5}\}$. Define $f: \mathbb{Z} → \mathbb{Z}_6$ by
   $f(m) =\bar{4m} ∈ \mathbb{Z}_6$ for all $m∈\mathbb{Z}$.

**My Attempt**

1. Yes
2. No, since $f(xy) \neq f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$
3. No, since $f(x+y) \neq f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$
4. Confused b/c $f(2*3) = \bar{24} = \bar{0}$ and $f(2)*f(3) = \bar{96} = \bar{0}$ (but $f(2*3) =24 = f(2)*f(3) = 96)$???

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument for 3 is incorrect. $h(xy) = (xy)^3 = x^3 y^3$... You may have wanted to say that $h(x+y)\neq h(x)+h(y)$. For 4, consider what happens to $1$ under $f$.

Comment: Thanks for correcting (3). I did $h(x+y) \neq h(x)+h(y)$ but wrote it wrong :)

Comment: Do you mean $m = 1$ and $n = 1$? If so, then $f(xy) = \bar{4}$ and $f(x)f(y) = \bar{16} = \bar{4}$

Comment: No, I don't. I mean to say that if you have two unital rings, then a homomorphism of the rings must send $1$ to $1$. Does that happen here..?